# React native router (V6) is not routing to a different page based on the endpoint, instead shows the same page for both routes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

```
import {NativeRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-native';
import Loader from  '../components/Loader';
import Home from '../components/Home';

export default function RoutingFunc(){
  return(
    <NativeRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Loader />} />
      </Routes>
    </NativeRouter>
  )
}
```

For both the routes `/` and `/home` ,the Loader component is being rendered

**Loader Component**

```
import { Box, Flex, Heading,Text } from "native-base";
import {Image} from 'react-native';

export default function Loader(){
  console.log(window.location.href)
  return(
    <Flex flexDirection="column" 
    justifyContent="center" 
    alignItems="center" 
    h="100%" 
    w="100vw"
    position="relative"
    backgroundColor="#25A9B0">
      <Heading color="white" fontSize="5xl">page<Text color="#05386B">in</Text></Heading>
      <Box position="absolute"
      top="55%"
      left="46%"
      backgroundColor="#36BAC2"
      w="45"
      h="45"
      borderRadius="full"
      borderColor="#05386B"
      borderWidth="2">
      </Box>
      <Box position="absolute"
      top="58%"
      left="49%"
      backgroundColor="#36BAC2"
      w="45"
      h="45"
      borderRadius="full"
      borderColor="#05386B"
      borderWidth="2">
      </Box>
      <Image source={require('../../resource/logo1.png')} />
      {/* <Text position="absolute" bottom="5%" fontSize="md">Randomized Text</Text> */}
    </Flex>
  )
}
```

**Home Component**

```
import {View,Text,Dimensions} from "react-native";
import Posts from "./Posts";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
         <View 
         style={{display:'flex',
         justifyContent:'center',
         width:'100%',
         height:`${Dimensions.get('window').height}px`,
         flexDirection:"column",
         overflow:'scroll'}}>
           <Posts/>
         </View>
         <Footer/>
        </>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: To be clear, `Home` and `Loader` are *actually* two different component? I see no issue with the code in the snippet. Can you include all relevant code in your question, the two components you are trying to render? Can you try creating a *running* [Expo Snack](https://expo.dev/) demo of your code we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Yes they are 2 different components

Answer (score 0):

I think the `/` is superfluous now for everything but the home route so what happens if you try the path (`/home`) without `/`. The matching logic in v6 has improved, so perhaps the below, and it will automatically match the most specific:

```
   <NativeRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Loader />} />
      </Routes>
    </NativeRouter>
```

Comment: Tried this before did not work